# I want to link css and js files in my vuejs project through index.html

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

It gives error -> because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled

```
<link href="../src/assets/css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Folder structure:

```
public
  index.html
src
  assets
    vendor
```

Comment: What do you get when requesting `../src/assets/css/sb-admin-2.min.css` in a browser?

Comment: And you are sure, the css file is located in `src/assets/css` ?
In your folder-structure is no `css` folder?